# Perl SQL::Parser table alias substitution: works for SELECT column names but not for WHERE column names

Tags: sql, perl, parsing

I'm trying to parse some SQL queries stored in a log database -- I don't want to submit them to a SQL database, just to extract the fields used in the SELECT and WHERE clause.

I've been fiddling with several SQL parsers in Java, Python and Perl. The one that seems to work better for my problem are SQL::Parser and SQL::Statement. With those I was able to write the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use SQL::Parser;
use SQL::Statement;

use Data::Dumper;

my $sql = "SELECT sl.plate,sp.fehadop FROM sppLines AS sl ".
          "JOIN sppParams AS sp ON sl.specobjid = sp.specobjid ".
          "WHERE fehadop < -3.5 ";

my $parser = SQL::Parser->new();
my $stmt = SQL::Statement->new($sql,$parser);
printf("COMMAND [%s]\n",$stmt->command);
printf("COLUMNS \n");
my @columns = @{$stmt->column_defs()};
foreach my $column ( @columns) 
  {
  print "   ".$column->{value}."\n";
  }
printf("TABLES \n");
my @tables = $stmt->tables();
foreach my $table ( @tables) 
  {
  print "   ".$table->{name}."\n";
  }
printf("WHERE COLUMNS\n");
my $where_hash = $stmt->where_hash();
print Dumper($where_hash);
```

Sorry if it is too long, it is the smallest, self-contained example I could devise.

The output of this code is:

```
COMMAND [SELECT]
COLUMNS 
   spplines.plate
   sppparams.fehadop
TABLES 
   spplines
   sppparams
WHERE COLUMNS
$VAR1 = {
          'arg1' => {
                      'value' => 'fehadop',
                      'type' => 'column',
                      'fullorg' => 'fehadop'
                    },
          'op' => '<',
          'nots' => {},
          'arg2' => {
                      'str' => '-?0?',
                      'fullorg' => '-3.5',
                      'name' => 'numeric_exp',
                      'value' => [
                                   {
                                     'fullorg' => '3.5',
                                     'value' => '3.5',
                                     'type' => 'number'
                                   }
                                 ],
                      'type' => 'function'
                    },
          'neg' => 0
        };
```

The parser returns the name of columns (obtained through a call to `$stmt->column_defs()`) already renamed with the real tables names (e.g. **spplines**.plate instead of **s1**.plate) -- this is what I want.

I also want the names of the columns used in the `WHERE` clause. 
I already know how to recursively parse the results of `$stmt->where_hash()` (didn't include the code to make the post clear), but even from dumping its contents I can see that the column names are not associated with the tables.

I would like to ensure that the columns names in the `WHERE` clause are also preceded by the tables name. After parsing the results of `$stmt->where_hash()` I would get sppparams.fehadop instead of fehadop.

Is this possible with SQL::Parser?

Thanks
(big edit -- tried to make the question clearer)

Comment: Can you please add the expected output in a bit clearer way? The lower part of the question is a bit of babbling.

Comment: I've edited the question, hope it is clearer how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since SQL::Statement has an `eval_where`, I suspect there might be a better way, but you can try a function like this:

```
get_column($stmt->column_defs(), $where_hash->{arg1});

sub get_column {
    my ($columns, $arg) = @_;
    return $arg->{fullorg} if ($arg->{type} ne 'column');
    foreach my $col (@$columns) {
        return $col->{value} if ($col->{fullorg} eq $arg->{fullorg});
        my ($name) = ( $col->{fullorg} =~ /([^.]+)$/);
        return $col->{value} if ($name eq $arg->{fullorg});
    }
    return $arg->{fullorg};
}
```

Comment: Thanks -- works for the simple case I posted. I have to think about dealing with more complex WHERE clauses. I am not sure `eval_where` is helpful in this case, I only need to extract full column names, not eval whether it matches values or not (unless I misunderstood what `eval_where` does -- documentation and examples are sparse!)

Comment: What I meant, is that since they have an eval function it is possible that they have a resolving deep in the source code somewhere. I didn't read that deep. Let me know if it doesn't work for your other cases.

Comment: Thanks for the hint -- I may need to get the source from that module and check anyway. I've just discovered that the parser complains about "select top 10 X,Y from..." (error: `Bad table or column name: 'TOP 10' has chars not alphanumeric or underscore`) -- I thought "select top" was standard SQL.

Comment: The answer to that is a bit long to do here, so it should be in a new question.